# Choice of hash table collision resolution depending on key and value type

Tags: hash-tables

Which kind of collision resolution for a hash table should I pick if I want to store a mapping

1. from key of type uint64 (word) to value of type uin64 (word)
2. from key of type string to value of type uint64

respectively?

Comment: I think that both questions require more input, what kind of mapping, how many numbers, what kind of strings, what is your goal? What inputs do you expect? Is it static or dynamic setting? Otherwise, pick any and it will work.

Comment: "Should" is subjective.  Is there a specific criteria you want to use to evaluate your solution?  Ease of programming (not too much effort to implement)?  Worst-case running time?  Average-case running time?  Asymptotics or not?  etc.

Comment: Also regarding uint64 keys, the distribution of the keys is important. However if it's skewed or far from being "random", you may apply avalanche function and still use "weak" collision resolution, like linear probing.